# Rspec google-api-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api-ruby-client

I am having difficulty creating tests to mock the google-api-client gem. Below is the method I am trying to test.

This method is expected to return all google calendars for a authenticated user.

```
def all_google_calendars

#create a google api client
client = Google::APIClient.new

#assign the google client an access token recieved during oauth
client.authorization.access_token = session[:oauth_token]

#specify the google api we wish to use
service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')

#execute google api method to get users calendar information
result = client.execute(:api_method => service.calendar_list.list)

#variable with only relevent calendar data
entries = result.data.items


#empty array to store calendar names
calendar_events = []


#iterate through each entry and extract summary. summary == name of calendar
entries.each do |e|
  calendar_events.push  'name' => e.summary, 'id' => e.id 
end


calendar_events

end
```

Here is the start of my rspec test:

```
let(:session) {{oauth_token: 'fake_token'}}

describe '#all_google_calendars' do

context 'when requesting a google calendar list' do

  it 'returns a users google calendars' do
    client = double('client')
    allow(client).to receive_message_chain('authorization.access_token')
    Google::APIClient = object_double(Google::APIClient, :new => client)

    allow(double).to receive_message_chain(:authorization, :access_token) {session[:oauth_token]}

    allow(Google::APIClient).to receive_message_chain(:new, :authorization, :access_token => session[:oauth_token]) { session[:oauth_token] }

    expect(controller.all_google_calendars).to eq(session[:oauth_token]) 
  end
end
end
```

I am getting an error

```
Double received unexpected message :access_token= with (nil)
```

Why is this chained message not getting mocked?
Thank you for any help!